# Designing for Android Tablets -- Magazine (PDF vs epub)

Tags: android

How does adobe digital publishing suite produce such nice tablet interactions for android devices?

Do they produce a pdf and have the app read it or is it something different?

I was able to prototype an application for the iPad using a pdf reader library and it looks and works great!

What options are there for displaying a magazine in an android tablet?

Comment: Adobe Digital Publishing Suites uses a proprietary format called Folio (http://offers.adobe.com/en/na/leap/landings/dps_folio.html). It is a XML based formats which describes how assets (images/videos/audio etc.) are arranged on a canvas.

The Viewer-App or Reader can interpret the .Folio-File and displays it. The graphics can be rasterized (JPEG/PNG) or vector-based (PDF). This means that both iOS and Android Viewers can display PDF-based graphics.

Answer (score 0):

On Android it's quite problematic "embedding" PDFs in applications.
You can't do it natively like you do on iOS, so your options are:

- find a commercial PDF plugin and write your app based on it.
  for example Foxit: http://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/embedded/android.php
  but you have to request a quote and prices may be high.

  - find a free open source plugin and embed it, but afaik, all are based on GPL PDF libraries, so you may have licensing problems.
  - use an external reader (like Adobe Acrobat or other free/open source readers) and call them from your app using Android Intents.

one other solution is use something like Adobe Digitap Publishing suite:
http://www.adobe.com/solutions/digital-publishing.html 
that works on iOS, Android and RIM playbook. 
you can create a customized reader app too, but you need to buy their suite, learn to use it, and maybe buy services as well.